# Cognos Headers/Footers

Tags: cognos

Does anyone know if it's possible to have more than one Overall Footer in a list? I am building a list that contains a 3 row table in each column, and the list is grouped by product. I would like two of these rows to show as overall totals for all products in the list. I have added an Overall Footer for one, which is summing correctly. I had to use a List Page Footer for the other which is returning the last amount in the list instead of summing. I tried to use 'Summarize' but since each column contains 3 separate rows of data, I'm not sure if this is possible. I'm trying to avoid creating separate data items for each column that will sum by product (ie total(Sales for Product)) because I have lots of columns and that will equate to lots of extra data items.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can have more than one header/footer row within a list. Click the list, then go to the 'Headers/Footers' button just to the right of Section/Pivot and add additional header and footer rows. By default they add as one merged row, but if you select if you can unmerge it into individual cells.

Hope Im following you here for the next part...

If you want to repeat the overall totals in one of these footer rows in the child table, I would do it via singletons. Having a parent/child relationship may force you to create an additional query which is just the total values. Then have the singletons reference that new query, not either the parent/child.

Answer (score 0):

Unlock the report, drag block/s in the footer where you want to repeat the summary data, drag your data items inside the block.